# Where should javascript code be?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, architecture

It should be in View part, where the html is, or not? If this javascript code is used just for that one file, it doesn't make sense to put it in main file of javascript, does it? Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use another Javascript file just for that page?  And the JS will HAVE to be in the HTML area, whether it's coded directly or linked to an external script.

Comment: @rockerest: Yeah, nice suggestion, I also was thinking about that, but if you need just like 10-15 code lines of javascript, then I don't know...

Comment: You should put it linked as a script tag in the base/layout HTML file, thought it should be in another file in your public/static/asset folder. Which framework are you using?

Comment: @hey you need 15 lines now, but tomorrow you'll be needing 15 more and so on...

Comment: @hey if they are likely to hit another page on your site then you would avoid having them download another file if you kept all the JS in one file. It comes down to a trade off between file size and http requests.

Comment: Transfer overhead for an additional 15 lines of code will probably be smaller than an additional HTTP request.

Comment: What is "main file of javascript"?  You don't necessarily have a single javascript file for all your pages.  If you have a common file that you link in every page, I'd consider that a library.  I wouldn't put stuff that is view specific in a library - only stuff that is common/library specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Inline JavaScript** does not require an additional HTTP request,
and can incorporate with PHP logic,
but for repeat visitor will need to fetch the 15 lines of JavaScript all over again.

Using a JavaScript file incurred an additional HTTP request,
with the proper expiration header,
it won't repeatedly request the JavaScript file.
Of course, you can not incorporate PHP logic into it.

There is no clear winner, much depend on your situation.
I prefer inline JavaScript as the flexibility to incorporate PHP logic is irreplaceable.

And [google](http://www.google.com) does that too!
By minify inline CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: @austincheney can you elaborate more?

Comment: Google markup code rarely validates against any commonly accepted scheme.  The markup in most of their tools appears to be mostly generated dynamically opposed to supplied statically, which for anybody else is horrible for SEO and potentially disastrous for accessibility.  If you look to bad examples as evidence of what you should do then you yourself will probably do badly and such will be reflected in the quality of output.

Comment: I think this is off-topic. Why dragging SEO into this? Or you are saying inline JavaScript bring bad effects to SEO?

Comment: I am saying that Google is a horrible example of how to write markup code correctly.  That is all I am saying.  Inline JavaScript infers the use of markup code to deliver JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In a `.js` file, linked by a `<script>` in your HTML view.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with prev answers. Cleaner to have it in a separate js file. Also to note that if possible, and there are very few cases where it's not, but I would recommend putting te references to te files at te bottom of the document and triggering functions, etc after the document is ready/loaded.  you may want to look at some utilities that can also help you organize what files get referenced on what page.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to access the javascript methods in more than one file. Then you should create a file with .js extension and place your methods or functions inside that file. Then open the files you actually want to access the javascript methods. between  ...  tags.  Place like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js">
```

http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jxtern.htm